# Operator overloading c++ >> istream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload the operator >> so that when I use cin>> I will be allowed to set my object's attributes,the overloading of << is working but not >>, here is my code.`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class fraction{
    private:
        int den;
        int nom;
    public:
        fraction(){nom=0;den=1;}
        fraction(int x,int y){nom=x;den=y;}
        fraction(const fraction &);
        ~fraction();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &,const fraction &);
        friend istream& operator>>(istream &,fraction &);
        fraction operator*(const fraction &);
        fraction operator/(const fraction &);
        fraction operator+(const fraction &);
        fraction operator-(const fraction &);
        friend void simple(fraction &);
};

istream operator>>(istream& is,fraction &v){
    is>>v.nom;
    is>>v.den;
    return is;
}
```

`
And here is the error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘std::istream operator>>(std::istream&, fraction&)’:
main.cpp:10:7: error: ‘int fraction::nom’ is private
main.cpp:53:4: error: within this context
main.cpp:9:7: error: ‘int fraction::den’ is private
main.cpp:54:4: error: within this context
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43:0, 
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:788:5: error:     ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:45:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_ios.h:64:11: error: within this context
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:41:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/istream: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/istream:56:11: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’ first required here 
main.cpp: In function ‘std::istream operator>>(std::istream&, fraction&)’:
main.cpp:55:9: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’ first required here
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: There is a `&` missing after `istream`, making the operator not match the declared friend.

Comment: Thank you xD. I didn't pay attention to that, I don't know how. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the function header for the overloaded operator as follows:

```
istream &operator>>(istream& is,fraction &v){
```

The & was missing for the return value.